# Secure entry text field and plain re-entry text field

Tags: forms

While using android banking application I found an unusual form style. This form is for adding new Beneficiary. It requires adding bank account number two times to avoid adding the wrong account number.

What I found different is first account number text field is secure and re-enter account number is the plain text field.

Here is that screen:

[image]

It doesn't make much sense for me because Account number is not much private detail and even if it is the second field is plain.

What one benefit I can think of is alertness. While making secure text field entry user become more alert because one can't read after making entry so the user tries to enter without mistake.

Is this only reason to do so or there are any other benefits of doing this?

Comment: Yes, i've seen these kind of patterns. My hunch is they want let the user know what he has entered. But again it is hard to know what he entered in masked input fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There are couple of benefits:**

1. If the secure text field is not provided, there are definitely chances of entering the same number by looking at the first input value in confirming field. What if a user entered a wrong number in the first field itself? This leads to mistake(s).
2. Since it is a secure text field, the user must look at the source to re-enter the number in the confirm field. This drastically reduces entering a wrong account number. I think, in most of the cases even if the user remembers the account number, they always cross check with the source to avoid mistakes.
3. Copy, Paste is not allowed.

But, still, I heard sometimes that the amount has been transferred to a different account number.

Answer (score 0):

I'm eager to find out what's the result of this. It's rather confusing because if a user was to be prompt an error, which one is the wrong input?

For bank validation, should it be trying to match account number, type to account holder name and ask for validation.